# Why i am getting an error code 10003 while updating documents in mongodb? I'm using mongodb version 3.2

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-update

```
db.FirstTry.update({"id":1},{$set:{"Name":"Selvah"}});
```

I am getting an error like this

> {     "message" : "WriteError({'code':10003,'index':0,'errmsg':'Cannot
>   change the size of a document in a capped collection: 72 !=
>   71','op':{'q':{'id':1},'u':{'$set':{'Name':'Selvah'}},'multi':false,'upsert':false}})",
>     "stack" : "script:1:55" +
>                 "script:1:13" }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of the document in a capped collection is fixed, so you cannot insert a new field into the document. You will have to create a new temp collection and copy all data from old collection to new collection and add new field.

Something like this:

```
db.createCollection( "logItems_temp", { capped: true, size: 100000 } )
var cur = db.logItems.find()
while (cur.hasNext()) {
  logItem = cur.next(); 
  if(logItem.name == null){
      logItem.name = selvah;
  }
  db.logItems_temp.insert(logItem);
}
db.logItems.drop()
db.logItems_temp.renameCollection("logItems")
```

Comment: Is there any way to insert new fields use the update command?  If possible can u just tell me

Comment: In a capped collection you cannot insert new fields as it will increase the size of the document. check official document here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/#document-size

Comment: But if you really want to do it, you'll have to copy documents to a new collection, update them and then create a new capped collection

Comment: yeah bro i got tat :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think this solves your Problem http://www.solidsyntax.be/2016/03/26/MongoDB-Cannot-change-the-size-of-a-document-in-a-capped-collection/

The official documentation lists Information about working with Capped collections: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/#restrictions-and-recommendations